# Calling method with params from method with params

Tags: c#, .net, parameters

I want to do the next:

```
void SomeMethod ()
{
  ParamMethod1 (1,2,3);
}

void ParamMethod1 (params object[] arg)
{
   ParamMethod2 (0, arg); //How to call ParamMethod2 in order to it works 
   //as I want
}

void ParamMethod2 (params object[] arg)
{
  //I want 'arg' contains 0,1,2,3 instead of 0, System.object[]
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with LINQ but you need still need ToArray()

```
ParamMethod2(new object [] { 0 }.Concat(arg).ToArray());
```

---

*Edited to Add:*

Based on the comment regarding performance I did some very basic performance comparisons between the suggested methods.

For 1 million calls

```
80ms -- Direct call: ParamMethod2(0,1,2,3);
280ms -- Using CopyTo
400ms -- Using LINQ
590ms -- Using AddRange
```

Of course if you changed object to int and a few other things you will improve performance further. Personally I'd use LINQ because it is fast enough for 99% of cases and in the other case I wouldn't use params in the first place.

Comment: Beware of this solution as Union returns a collection of distinct objects. [0] union [0,1,2] => [0,1,2] and [0] union [0,0,1,1,2,2] => [0,1,2]

Comment: @LasseDahlEbert I have updated my answer to use Concat, which is what it should have been.

Comment: There are more efficient ways to do this, but it's always fun to see unique solutions.

Comment: @Steven Thanks for the performance tests ... these micro-optimizations are useless, and I'm much happier to see a single line solution!  
... Still, the mathematician inside me wants to mention that as you add more parameters, you'll see `CopyTo` is `O(n)`, `AddRange` is `O(n)`, and `LINQ` is `O(n lg n)`.

Answer (score 1):

One way, though not necessarily ideal, could simply be:

```
void ParamMethod1 (params object[] arg)
{
    var args = new List<object>();
    args.Add(0);
    if (arg != null)
    {
        args.AddRange(arg);
    }        
    ParamMethod2(args.ToArray());
}
```

That is to say, regardless of how this is done, we need to combine `0` and the contents of `arg` into a single collection - there will doubtless be a more efficient way, and perhaps even a simpler approach that I can't see for lack of coffee this morning, but this will do the trick, so to speak.

Comment: 2 problems. 1) OP asked for the `0` to be at the start, you can just move your `arg.Add(0)` to before the `if`. 2) You need `args.ToArray()` at the end when calling `ParamMethod2` as `List<object>` wont implicitly cast to `object[]`.

Comment: @Jamiec Noticed the misplacing of `0` - `ToArray` is and was there, though.

Comment: To optimize, you could use the `List<>(capacity)` constructor. But @Jamiec's solution is probably the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
void ParamMethod1 (params object[] arg)
{
   if(arg == null || arg.Length == 0)
   {
      ParamMethod2(0);
      return;
   }
   var newArray = new int[arg.Length + 1];
   newArray[0] = 0;
   arg.CopyTo(newArray,1);
   ParamMethod2 (newArray); 
}
```

Comment: If `arg` is `null` this will go _BANG!_ Also, requires a capital L for `Length`.

Comment: +1 for the most direct, efficient answer! The other solutions could have easily been optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Change this method

> void ParamMethod2 (params object[] arg)
>   {
>     //I want 'arg' contains 0,1,2,3 instead of 0, System.object[]
>   }

To

> void ParamMethod2 (int firstValue, params object[] arg)
>   {
>     //Now, firstvalue always will have 0 and remaining passed variables will have 1,2,3, etc.
>   }

Hope this is what your asking for.

Note here that you will have a problem if you want to have a method with only params as arguments, because always your compiler will call this explicit first argument signature than params only signature method.

Comment: +1 This solution is a little less valid in the hypothetical example the OP is currently written as, but is a good suggestion to consider for real life use.

Comment: Yes its very hypothetical such solutions gets implemented in production code, but no harm in knowing about it. Any ways thanks :)

Comment: Yes its very hypothetical such solutions gets implemented in production code, but no harm in knowing about it. Any ways thanks :)